# Post a message to slack from c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, slack-api

I am trying to post a message on the #general channel and this worked when was doing it through a console app but Now I am using MVC and the message doesn't seem to get posted. Also, earlier I was using the webhook URL and now I am using the access token that I have.

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace SlackClient.Controllers
{
    public class SlackClient
    {
        private readonly Uri _uri;
        private readonly Encoding _encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

        public SlackClient(string urlWithAccessToken)
        {
            _uri = new Uri(urlWithAccessToken);
        }

        //Post a message using simple strings
        public void PostMessage(string text, string username = null, string channel = null)
        {
            Payload payload = new Payload()
            {
                Channel = channel,
                Username = username,
                Text = text
            };

            PostMessage(payload);
        }

        //Post a message using a Payload object
        public void PostMessage(Payload payload)
        {
            string payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
                data["payload"] = payloadJson;

                var response = client.UploadValues(_uri, "POST", data);

                //The response text is usually "ok"
                string responseText = _encoding.GetString(response);
            }
        }
    }

    //This class serializes into the Json payload required by Slack Incoming WebHooks
    public class Payload
    {
        [JsonProperty("channel")]
        public string Channel { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the other class is SlackClientTest.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SlackClient.Controllers
{
    public class SlackClientTest
    {
        void TestPostMessage()
        {
            string urlWithAccessToken = "https://srishti2604.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=my-tokenHere.";

            SlackClient client = new SlackClient(urlWithAccessToken);

            client.PostMessage(username: "Mr. Torgue",
                       text: "THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE! SQUEEDLYBAMBLYFEEDLYMEEDLYMOWWWWWWWW!",
                       channel: "#general");
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me what might me wrong?

My console app looks like this

SlackClient.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SlackProject1
{
    public class SlackCient
    {

        private readonly Uri _webhookUrl;
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        public SlackCient(Uri webhookUrl)
        {
            _webhookUrl = webhookUrl;
        }

        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessageAsync(string message,
            string channel = null, string username = null)
        {
            var payload = new
            {
                text = message,
                channel,
                username,
            };
            var serializedPayload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_webhookUrl,
                new StringContent(serializedPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SlackProject1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(IntegrateWithSlackAsync());
        }

        private static async Task IntegrateWithSlackAsync()
        {
            var webhookUrl = new Uri("https://hooks.slack.com/services/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");
            var slackClient = new SlackCient(webhookUrl);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Type a message: ");
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
                var response = await slackClient.SendMessageAsync(message);
                var isValid = response.IsSuccessStatusCode ? "valid" : "invalid";
                Console.WriteLine($"Received {isValid} response.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what actually happens when you run this code? Does it finish running?

Comment: Sounds like you've got too many variables.  You moved from a working _console app + webhook_ to a non-functional _ASP.NET + access token_.   Try changing one thing at a time.  I recommend you go back to the console app and see how it goes with the access token technique.  Once you have that working, try ASP.NET with the token

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It runs and goes to the redirect uri that I set in the app. On the channel it just says that the admin which is me added an integration to this channel.

Comment: @User453465436754 The console app was a totally different project and I wanted to have the Oauth 2.0 too so I switched to MVC and first finished the OAuth 2.0 flow as provided by slack documentation. Now, when I have the access token, I want to use it to post messages to channel. However, this give me a partial result and I cannot figure out how to go about it.

Comment: Of course it's _"a totally different project"_ - one is a console app, the other isn't.  However, both aim to do the same and you've changed **too much too soon**

Comment: So what should I do now? I will share my console app code above. Could you help  me from there?